# Sequence not matching element

Tags: c#

I have a question about an exception.

My client says that sometimes it appears this error message:

> sequence contains no matching element.

But when I check from my computer it doesn't have any problem. It just happens sometimes at my client.
After I checked the log it says that the problem is in this line of code:

```
 var firstRc = entity.Right.Components.First(r => r.CadastralObjectId == parentCadastralObjectId
                                && r.ValidityEndCaseId == null
                                && r.IsLive == false);
```

Should I try to use `FirstOrDefault` instead of just `First`?

Comment: Yes, use `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: It is always recommended to use FirstOrDefault, due to the fact that it not throws an error if it not match anything.

Comment: @user2568960 Use `FirstOrDeafault()`- MSDN _says_ **Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements.**

Comment: Ok, I am will use it now, but sometimes it happens that it dessappears some javascript columns, does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

Method [`First`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx) throws an [`InvalidOperationException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.invalidoperationexception(v=vs.100).aspx) if given sequence is empty.

Method [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx) returns [`default(T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) if given sequence is empty.

Answer (score 1):

`First()` will throw an exception if it can't find any matching elements.so use `FirstOrDefault()`, which returns the default value for the element type (which is null for reference types) if no matching items are found

change to

```
var firstRc = entity.Right.Components.FirstOrDefault(r => r.CadastralObjectId == parentCadastralObjectId
                                                     && r.ValidityEndCaseId == null
                                                     && r.IsLive == false);
```

Comment: Saying you should use `FirstOrDefault` is not really correct. `First` exists for a reason, not only because they didn't remove it when `FirstOrDefault` was written. Sometimes you want to use `First` if lack of an item is truly an error.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you should use `First` or `FirstOrDefault` depends on whether you think there should always be something returned or not.

If there should always be something then using First and having an exception thrown is correct. It is an error that there is nothing there and `First` will throw an exception which is exactly what you want.

If it is expected that sometimes there won't be a match then use `FirstOrDefault` and then deal with the default (probably a null) as appropriate.

Which is most appropriate for your application is something only you can answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should prefer FirstOrDefault instead of First.
Becuase First have to find at least and only one element.

Comment: `First` doesn't have to find only one element. That's `Single` that you are thinking of. And if the expectation is that there should always be at least one element and its an error if not then `First` is completely appropriate here. Using FirstOrDefault will just move the error further from its actual source.

Comment: First returns the first element of a sequence, right. throw InvalidOperationException when sequence is empty. FirstOrDefault return default. --null for reference type.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`First`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx) method only if the query should *always* match at least one element and when you need only the first element of the matched group. The method will throw `InvalidOperationException` if the sequence is empty.

If you expect the query to *always* match *exactly one* element, then use the [`Single`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb155325(v=vs.100).aspx) method. It will throw `InvalidOperationException` if the sequence is empty, or if the sequence contains more than one element.

But, if it is expected that sometimes a query may match no elements, then you should use either [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx) or [`SingleOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342451(v=vs.100).aspx) method. They will both return a default value, if the sequence is empty. It means that in case of reference types the return value will be `null`, so you should probably add some additional checks for `null`. Also, mind that `SingleOrDefault` will still throw, if the sequence contains more than one element.